# Adding columns from multiple files with numbered names

Tags: command-line, text-processing

I have a lot of files named like this: DOS1, DOS2, DOS3, DOS4, ..., DOS128. Each file contains four columns (first column is the same) with numbers, like this:

DOS1 is:

```
33 12 1 2
16 32 8 1
9  90 17 5
...
```

DOS2 is:

```
33 1 2 1
16 3 4 3
9  1 1 1
...
```

I would like to sum the second, third and four column from specified DOSX files, for example DOS1 and DOS2, to get DOS_sum:

```
33 13 3 3
16 35 12 4
9  91 18 6
...
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `awk`:

```
awk '{a[FNR]=$1;b[FNR]+=$2;c[FNR]+=$3;d[FNR]+=$4} END{for (i=1;i<=FNR;i++) print a[i], b[i], b[i], d[i]}' DOS1 DOS2 > DOS_sum
```

More readably:

```awk
{
    a[FNR]=$1     # Keep the first column
    b[FNR]+=$2    # Sum the rest. FNR is the current line number 
    c[FNR]+=$3    # in the current file. So this accumulates
    d[FNR]+=$4    # the values of a given line number across files.
}
END {
    for (i=1; i<=FNR; i++) 
        print a[i], b[i], c[i], d[i]
}
```

Use bash's brace expansion to sum a sequence of files:

```
awk '{a[FNR]=$1;b[FNR]+=$2;c[FNR]+=$3;d[FNR]+=$4} END{for (i=1;i<=FNR;i++) print a[i], b[i], b[i], d[i]}' DOS{10..73}
```

Comment: Dear muru,
thank you for prompt response. There is a small typo: a{FNR]=$1 -> a[FNR]=$1.After correction it works perfect, do you have an idea how to sum up more specified files without giving their name by hand? For example, sum up columns (with method you gave) of files let say from DOS10 to DOS73.

Comment: @Piotr ah, sorry about that.

Comment: For a sequence of files, use brace expansion. See update

Comment: Thank You again, it seems that everything works fine. Great job :D